# PostgreSQL UPDATE with conditional

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

```
UPDATE vaccine SET country_code = CASE
WHEN vaccine_country='Germany' THEN  country_code ='DE'
WHEN vaccine_country='United States'THEN country_code='US'
WHEN vaccine_country='China' THEN country_code='CN'
WHEN vaccine_country='Turkey' THEN country_code='TR'
WHEN vaccine_country='Russia' THEN country_code='RU'
END
```

I have a query like that, the [image]query is working without any error but the table is not updating after executing the query

Comment: do you have values like vaccine_country='Germany', 'Russia' in  vaccine  table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `country_code` after the `THEN`

```
UPDATE vaccine SET country_code = CASE
  WHEN vaccine_country='Germany' THEN  'DE'
  WHEN vaccine_country='United States'THEN 'US'
  WHEN vaccine_country='China' THEN 'CN'
  WHEN vaccine_country='Turkey' THEN 'TR'
  WHEN vaccine_country='Russia' THEN 'RU'
END;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ffcda9e14b9bc3216439f5bac2bb77e2)

Answer (score 2):

A CASE expressions returns a single *value* it's not a replacement for an assignment.

Your current THEN expressions all return a `boolean` expression that compares the (current) value of the column `country_code` with the constant on the right hand side. You need to remove the comparison with the target column in your CASE expression:

```
UPDATE vaccine 
  SET country_code = CASE
                      WHEN vaccine_country='Germany' THEN 'DE'
                      WHEN vaccine_country='United States' THEN 'US'
                      WHEN vaccine_country='China' THEN 'CN'
                      WHEN vaccine_country='Turkey' THEN 'TR'
                      WHEN vaccine_country='Russia' THEN 'RU'
                    END
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
UPDATE vaccine 
  SET country_code = CASE vaccine_country
                      WHEN 'Germany' THEN 'DE'
                      WHEN 'United States' THEN 'US'
                      WHEN 'China' THEN 'CN'
                      WHEN 'Turkey' THEN 'TR'
                      WHEN 'Russia' THEN 'RU'
                    END
```

Another option is to provide the mapping with a `VALUES` clause instead of a CASE expression:

```
UPDATE vaccine 
   SET country_code = t.country_code
FROM ( 
  values 
     ('Germany', 'DE'), 
     ('United States' , 'US'),
     ('China' , 'CN')
     ('Turkey' , 'TR')
     ('Russia' , 'RU')
) AS t(country, country_code)
where vaccine.country = t.country;
```

---

Note that for rows where the `vaccine_country` does not contain any of the listed countries, the country_code will be set to `NULL` which might or might not be what you want.